# Switching Nodes in a double linked list causes infinite recursion

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I have the following Node constructor:

```
const Node = function(data){
  this.data = data
  this.next = null
  this.previous = null
}
```

that is used inside of my LinkedList constructor:

```
const LinkedList = function(){
  this.head = new Node('head')
}
```

and I can insert nodes with the following method:

```
LinkedList.prototype.insert = function(item,after){
  const newNode = new Node(item)
  const curr = after ? this.find(after) : this.head
  newNode.next = curr.next
  newNode.previous = curr
  curr.next = newNode
}
```

with the `find` method being:

```
LinkedList.prototype.find = function(item){
  let currentNode = this.head
  while(currentNode && currentNode.data !== item){
    currentNode = currentNode.next
  }
  return currentNode
}
```

And can view the items as an array with the following method:

```
LinkedList.prototype.toArray = function(){
  const arr = []
  let currItem = this.head.next
  while(currItem){
    arr.push(currItem.data)
    currItem = currItem.next
  }
  return arr
}
```

My issue is now I am trying to implement a `switch` function on the LinkedList where I can pass in two values and switch their location in the list. Below is what I have and it seems to work for items that are not next to each other:

```
LinkedList.prototype.switch = function(a,b){
  const aNode = this.find(a),
        bNode = this.find(b)
  if(!aNode || !bNode){
    throw new Error('Both nodes were not inside of the list')
  }
  const aNext = aNode.next,
        aPrevious = aNode.previous,
        bNext = bNode.next,
        bPrevious = bNode.previous

  aNode.next = bNext
  aNode.previous = bPrevious
  aNode.previous.next = aNode

  bNode.next = aNext
  bNode.previous = aPrevious
  bNode.previous.next = bNode

}
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong here that is causing this to make my computer hit infinite recursion when I swap elements that are right next to each other. For instance, the below lines of code works:

```
const list = new LinkedList()
list.insert(1)
list.insert(2,1)
list.insert(3,2)
list.switch(1,3)
list.toArray() // [3,2,1]
```

However if I have the following code, it

```
const list = new LinkedList()
list.insert(1)
list.insert(2,1)
list.switch(1,2)
list.toArray() // crashes terminal
```

I know it is a stupid logical error in my `switch` method but I cannot for the life of me figure out what.

Comment: Where's the `find()` function?

Comment: @Pointy edited the post to show the find method

Comment: I think you need to grab the values of `.previous.next` for both entries before re-assigning.

Comment: If `b` is directly after `a`, then `aNode.previous = bPrevious` will cause `aNode.previous` to point to itself, because `b.previous` was `aNode`. Then the very next line is `aNode.previous.next = aNode`, and since `aNode.previous` is a reference to `aNode`, the `aNode.next` will now also be a reference back to `aNode`.

Comment: @squint that is EXACTLY what is happening. I am just not sure of how to reason about handling that scenario

Comment: The cleanest way to go would be creating new nodes instead of using the pointers. Simply put `aNode = new Node(this.find(a))` and `bNode = new Node(this.find(b))` before you begin to fill them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I see is in your insert function. If you have a linked list with two items and you call insert('New Node', null) your list looks like this:

[image]

You still need to set the previous pointer to the new node like this:

```
LinkedList.prototype.insert = function(item,after){
  const newNode = new Node(item);
  const curr = after ? this.find(after) : this.head;
  newNode.next = curr.next;
  curr.next.previous = newNode; <----- This is the extra line
  newNode.previous = curr;
  curr.next = newNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `bNode.previous` is `null`, and if you assign as the following,

```
  aNode.previous = bPrevious
  aNode.previous.next = aNode
```

then you are trying to reach the `next` field of `null`, which causes to crash.

Comment: I don't understand why a `null` would cause infinite recursion. It should simply throw an error.

Comment: Why do you think it causes "infinite recursion"? I cannot tell from your question, since you have not provided the error or what you see in the terminal.